# Swift SceneKit issue with node position on preview

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to add nodes to my scene view, but all of the nodes have a zero position, but different placements.

Each node has a position (0,0,0) but, on the scene view, this node has a different placement. Also, I can`t find the distance between nodes because each node has a position (0, 0, 0). Please explain to me what is wrong with my nodes.

Comment: Can you show some code about what you are writing ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the real position of a node try this:

```
node.presentation.worldPosition
```

This should always return you the effective position of the node as seen on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in 3d object, the original position of the 3d was not centered. I upload each 3c object to Blender and change original position to (0,0,0)